# Regex match till end of text

Tags: regex

I'm using Regex to match whole sentences in a text containing a certain string. This is working fine as long as the sentence ends with any kind of punctuation. It does not work however when the sentence is at the end of the text without any punctuation.

This is my current expression:

```
 [^.?!]*(?<=[.?\s!])string(?=[\s.?!])[^.?!]*[.?!]
```

Works for:

> This is a sentence with **string**. More text.

Does not work for:

> More text. This is a sentence with **string**

Is there any way to make this word as intended? I can't find any character class for "end of text".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

End of text is matched by the anchor `$`, not a character class.

You have two separate issues you need to address:  (1) the sentence ending directly after **string**, and (2) the sentence ending sometime after **string** but with no end-of-sentence punctuation.

To do this, you need to make the match after `string` optional, but anchor that match to the end of the string.  This also means that, after you recognize an (optional) end-of-sentence punctuation mark, you need to match everything that follows, so the end-of-string anchor will match.

My changes:  Take everything after `string` in your original regex and surround it in `(?:...)?` - the `(?:...)` being a "non-remembered" group, and the `?` making the entire group optional.  Follow that with `$` to anchor the end of the string.

Within that optional group, you also need to make the end-of-sentence itself optional, by replacing the simple `[.?!]` with `(?:[.?!].*)?` - again, the `(?:...)` is to make a "non-remembered" group, the `?` makes the group optional - and the `.*` allows this to match as much as you want after the end-of-sentence has been found.

```
[^.?!]*(?<=[.?\s!])string(?:(?=[\s.?!])[^.?!]*(?:[.?!].*)?)?$
```

Answer (score 3):

The symbol for end-of-text is `$` (and, the symbol for beginning-of-text, if you ever need it, is `^`).

You probably won't get what you're looking for with by just adding the `$` to your punctuation list though (e.g., `[.?!$]`); you'll find it works better as an alternative choice: `([.?!]|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is way too complex for what you want to achieve.

To match only a word just use

```
"\bstring\b"
```

It will match start, end and any non-alphanum delimiters.

It works with the following:

```
string is at the start
this is the end string
this is a string.
stringing won't match (you don't want a match here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the language in the question for more information about using.

Here is my example using javascript:

```js
var reg = /^([\w\s\.]*)string([\w\s\.]*)$/;

console.log(reg.test('This is a sentence with string. More text.'));

console.log(reg.test('More text. This is a sentence with string'));

console.log(reg.test('string'))
```

**Note:**

`*` : Match zero or more times.

? : Match zero or one time.

`+` : Match one or more times.

You can change `*` with ? or + if you want more definition.